# How to use and format Dynamic Inventory - Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Trying to format a valid dynamic inventory. How is this done?

This is for a script, that will take state file of terraform and make it to a usable inventory. I need to know the format of the dynamic inventory used in Ansible.
I tried to run the inventory below: `ansible all -i test.json -m ping`

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": { }
    },

    "instances": {
        "hosts": ["10.66.70.33"]
    }
}
```

Result:

```
 [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/test.json with yaml plugin: Invalid "hosts" entry for "instances" group,
requires a dictionary, found "<type 'list'>" instead.

 [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/test.json with ini plugin: /etc/ansible/test.json:2: Expected
key=value host variable assignment, got: {

 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/test.json as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

{ | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname {: Temporary failure in name resolution", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a format that worked:

```
{
   "all": {
      "hosts": "10.66.70.33",
      "children": {
         "instances": {
            "hosts": {
               "10.66.70.33":
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```